# How to move Odoo 10 filestore to different directory

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, odoo

I have 25 GB of Odoo 10.0 filestore on ubuntu server under `/home/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/Filestore`.
My database size is 5GB.

Now i want to move entire filestore to new directory `/srv/`

However in `.conf` file i have added following

```
data_dir=/srv/
```

When i do this all Odoo icons and attachments lost.

How i can move filestore from one location to another?

Comment: Make sure the user your that is running your server has the proper permissions to access `/srv/`

Comment: Also make sure that in the table `ir_attachment` of the database there are no reference to the old path.